# Compiling and running c++ apps in different Ubuntu version

Tags: c++, ubuntu

I've been trying to find a way to make my applications compatible between different Ubuntu LTS versions.

However, most of the time it ends up with the ***"symbol lookup error:"*** or ***"cannot find libxxxx.so.xx"***.

The requirement is very clear, developer should be able to compile the code on one of last 3 Ubuntu LTS (currently 12,14,16-04) versions and the output should be able to run on all 3 last versions. But the problem is getting complex.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post more details, like which library you are having problems with and what your compile/link command line(s) look like.

Comment: i'm using qt creator so didn't bother with the compile/link options up to now. to give an example opencv, ffmpeg(or avutils), swscale, cairo etc.. even gcc's itself may use different versions of libraries during compilation. Also some shared libraries are required in runtime (not on startup) so they are another headace.

Comment: So presumably you are asking how to use cmake to build your project?

Comment: Hmm.. To be honest I do not have any clear idea what should I ask first (or from where to start) in this problem. So all suggestions are also very welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Linux binaries compiled on older distributions are *generally* compatible with newer ones. The kernel invests a lot of effort in being backwards compatible - as does glibc. This may not be true for all libraries, but in my experience; most try.
So, what you probably want to do is, compile your app on the oldest supported distro and it will most likely work on the newer one(s).

Comment: ... provide the newer ones do have the same runtime libraries that your binary was built against.

Comment: Guess the hint was not strong enough for me, or I had too little coffee.  But yours is a good answer and I upvoted it.  (Also provided an alternative in another answer.)

Answer (score 2):

A really simple trick is to ... compile from source on the appropriate distro.

You can even almost automate this as Ubuntu / Canonical give you free accounts on Launchpad.  For example, I use my PPA for either backports or unpackaged sources I want at either work, or home, or on Travis CI, ... in a particular release flavour.

Otherwise, the very obvious alternative is of course to create a *static* build which is independent of the runtimes of the particular release.  That will work 'forever' or until the kernel changes.  In the 20+ years I have used Linux, such a change occurred once (with the introduction of the Elf format).